# How to upgrade PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, php

So i did simple thing:

```
php -i | head
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-snmp
make
sudo make install
```

But `phpinfo()` still showing me 5.3.15. Here some results of investigations:

- PHP_BINDIR = /usr/bin
- phpversion() = 5.3.15
- 192-168-0-100:$ /usr/bin/php -v
  PHP 5.4.8 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2012 09:30:58)
- 192-168-0-100:$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
  PHP 5.4.8 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2012 22:09:56)
- 192-168-0-100:$ which php 
  /usr/bin/php

Also tried plying with different ln -s. May be some suggestions?

P.S.
php is working fine on localhost, but it is still 5.3 (tried some new features from php 5.4)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building yourself and potentially wreaking havoc in your `/bin` directory—this might kill your original PHP installation—do yourself a favor and use prebuilt installations like those below.

---

#### MAMP

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html) currently ships with PHP 5.2 and 5.4.4. It'll run standalone and you can switch anytime.

> MAMP is installed in the typical Mac fashion: very easily. MAMP will not compromise any existing Apache installation already running with your OS X. You can install Apache, PHP and MySQL without starting a script or having to change any configuration files!

#### PHP Binary Packages

You can also try the [PHP 5.3/5.4 for OS X](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) as binary packages:

> This package installs the (usually) latest PHP 5.3.x/5.4.x […] in /usr/local/php5. It installs many useful extensions […]. It also provides a decent php.ini with all settings configured according to "Best Practices".

For PHP 5.4, installation is as easy as running:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4
```

Comment: Alternatively, I would recommend installing with homebrew